# pvlib allows the discretization of the terrain to define areas with different albedo values?

Tags: python, pvlib

I want to discretize the terrain to quantify the impact on the bifacial gain that a reflective surface, installed on certains zones of the ground would have, is it something that pvlib could allow or should I enter to modify the code? Which tool (like MoBiDiG, pvfactors, bifacial_radiance, etc) would help me with this?

Thanks!!

Comment: pvlib can definitely not do this. Without knowing much, I would recommend you to look into pvfactors

Comment: @adamjensen if im right pvfactors is a sub library of pvlib, the last uses pvfactors to determinate the view factors between surfaces

Comment: pvlib does not have sub libraries and pvfactors has been developed independently of pvlib. I'm sure though that many user results from pvfactors in the modelling steps in pvlib.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [bifacial radiance](https://github.com/nrel/bifacial_radiance). I agree with Adam Jensen, pvlib cannot do this currently.